# The app couldn't be installed through Apple TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight

When i try to install my app through TestFlight, getting an alert shown below.
The invitation has been revoked or is invalid. please request a new invite from the developer when i try to install new build in testflight.

Everytime i have to create new build, At that time it will work fine. Is there any method to solve the above issue
Anyone know the expiry of the Build of iOS Application in TestFlight.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is happening with us as well, something is wrong with iTunes right now.

Comment: @blueice  Thanks for the information. I spent lot of time on this. Hope they will solve the issue very soon.

Comment: just so you know, even though I was having those issues with TestFlight, my app was approved and the installation on the devices had no issues.

Comment: @blueice Anyway that's great. I think this will happen with only external testers who try to install app. It getting installed in Internal testers device.

Answer (score 0):

After the 30-days-period You Build is expired , your test won't be able download or run your app. You can't  extend this period. You only can upload an updated version to get another 30 days.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information. But i am getting this error message when i send the new build to tester within 3  or 4 days. First time i successfully installed the app through TestFlight.